# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "tirar millas"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, coloquialismos, españa, modismos

Con frecuencia se utiliza *tirar millas* para designar algo o alguien que se marcha, que se larga o a quien se urge a hacerlo:

> — Mamá, no quiero hacer los deberes.
>   — Anda, ve a tu habitación a hacerlos y **tira millas**.

O bien

> Ayer mi jefe me pidió un informe a última hora. Hice un apañillo, se lo envié y **tira millas**.

Como todos sabemos, [*milla*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PFzx5LA) es una unidad de distancia terrestre o náutica. Se me ocurre que combinado con *tirar* podría tener algún origen "transportístico", en tanto a que se dijera *tirar millas* para designar a un barco que se largara de la costa. Sin embargo, en el DLE no encuentro ninguna acepción de [*tirar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Zr3ZJPx) que vaya en ese sentido, solamente esto:

> [**tirar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Zr3ZJPx)
>   24. intr. Dicho de personas, animales o vehículos: Hacer fuerza para traer hacia sí o para llevar tras sí.
>        (...)
>   30. intr. Dirigirse a uno u otro lado. Al llegar a la esquina, tire usted a la derecha.

¿Alguien sabe pues el origen de esta expresión? ¿Podríais también delimitar el uso que se hace, distinguiendo si su uso es siempre en un tono algo despectivo? ¿Se usa en otros lugares además de España?

Comment: No creo que se use siempre de forma despectiva. A mí su uso me suena más a como se usa en este ejemplo del CREA: "Luego me iré con un camión por la carretera a tirar millas por Italia." Simplemente indica que vas a recorrer mucha carretera.

Comment: En ese caso *tirar* yo diría que si encaja con la acepción 30: Dirigirse a uno u otro lado. Es como cuando dices *tira p'alante* con un significado similar a *tira millas*.

Comment: Puse la etiqueta 'españa' porque nunca he oído la expresión a este lado del Atlántico. Si me equivoco pues la quitamos :-)

Comment: @blonfu ciertamente, estoy de acuerdo en que la acepción 30 concuerda.

Comment: @blonfu ¿entonces podría ser una expresión marítima por ejemplo?

Comment: Ni idea, es difícil encontrar información sobre esa expresión. No he descubierto casi nada

Comment: En algunos diccionarios aparece también el nombre *tiramillas* definido como _"Persona que recorre velozmente grandes distancias a pie o en cualquier vehículo."_

Answer (score 3):

Creo que el origen de la expresión está en el método naútico del cálculo de velocidad.

El método está explicado un poco más abajo. "Tirar millas" era algo muy común en los barcos para medir la velocidad cuando no hay referencias físicas para medir distancias.

Alguien que se sube en un barco "tira millas", proceso necesario para saber velocidad y así calcular tiempo y distancia (aproximados) a un punto del mapa.

Método tradicional para la medición de velocidad en los barcos:

> La corredera era un método de medición que utilizaba una placa de madera, generalmente con forma de arco y con un peso en uno de los
>   extremos para que flotara en vertical en el agua. La placa se ataba a
>   una cuerda fina y larga con nudos distribuidos en espacios
>   equidistantes.
>
> Un marinero lanzaba la madera al agua junto con la cuerda arrastrando
>   mientras otro utilizaba un reloj de arena para medir el número de
>   nudos que discurrían en un intervalo de tiempo determinado, midiendo
>   así la velocidad del barco en número de nudos.
>
> El intervalo entre los nudos y el tiempo varió al principio, pero una
>   versión de esta herramienta de mediados del siglo XVIII (descrita en
>   Relación histórica del viaje hecho de orden de su Majestad a la
>   América Meridional, de Jorge Juan y Antonio de Ulloa) establecía los
>   nudos a 1/120 de una milla cada 30 segundos.
>
> **Desde entonces todo esto se ha estandarizado basándose en la milla**
>   náutica, que equivale a 1,852 kilómetros. Un nudo equivale por tanto a
>   una milla náutica por hora que a su vez equivale a 1,852 km/h.
>   [fuente](http://es.gizmodo.com/por-que-se-mide-la-velocidad-de-los-barcos-en-nudos-1543713924)

Comment: O sea que se pasaría de _tirar nudos_ a _tirar millas_, que sería equivalente de _navegar_. Bien expuesto

Comment: No veo la relación de ese texto con la expresión "tirar millas", explica porque se mide la velocidad en nudos en el mar y el valor de la milla náutica. Dices que "tirar millas" es medir la velocidad en un barco ¿Puedes aportar algún ejemplo? He buscado bastante y no he encontrado nada sobre eso.

Comment: Es una hipótesis. He seguido investigando y quizá tenga que ver con las vías romanas que tenían "miliarios" y eran recorridas por mensajeros constantemente. Estoy investigando esta hipótesis antes de escribir una respuesta.