# Are any of the pre-metric terms for weights and measures still used in Spanish?

Tags: vocabulario

While answering another question I used the English word furlong which is obsolete in usage, at least in the UK, except for in horse racing. This set me thinking about Spanish usage. For instance I remember colleagues referring to different sizes of floppy discs using the term *pulgada* but that I suppose is really because they were originally named in inches in English and converting to an exact number of millimetres would have been absurd.

There is a long list of candidates in the Spanish edition of Wikipedia [here](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiguas_medidas_espa%C3%B1olas). Are any of these still in popular use? I think we should probably exclude any which are only used in a stock phrase like the English phrase "To hide one's light under a bushel"

It would be best if there is an example of a whole area of application which has clung to the old system like the example of horse racing in the UK which still uses the old terms for both weight and length.

Comment: We also measure TV and monitor sizes in inches. Just to clarify, in the answers we should avoid sentences like ["tirar millas"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22083/12637), shouldn't we?

Comment: Considero esta pregunta un poco "too broad". Sugiero crear un post-respuesta tipo wiki con esas entradas, y que la gente diga para cada una si sí o si no, como en el comentario de Carlos. O quizá yo no entiendo la pregunta. Qué tipo de respuesta se espera para esta pregunta?

Comment: @Diego ¿el comentario de qué Carlos? :-D En todo caso, no pide una lista, sino solo si alguno se usa, es una pregunta de sí/no.

Comment: **Plamo** también se usa. Por ejemplo ["No levanta ni un palmo del suelo](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/el-no-levanta-un-palmo-del-suelo.774390/?hl=es). Igual con **dedo** si no me equivoco. Quien no tiene "dos **dedos** de frente" es porque tiene un cráneo reducido en el que no cabe un cerebro.

Comment: @Diego pero pide evitar frases hechas como las que mencionas, sino cosas que de verdad sea habitual medir con alguna de las medidas pre-sistema métrico.

Comment: @Diego I am not looking for a list, if even a few are used that is enough. I think the examples you quote are rather like "hiding your light under a bushel" which I was trying to avoid although it is difficult to know where to draw the line.

Comment: @Diego I have edited the question to try to narrow the focus a bit.

Comment: En algunos sitios se usa la libra todavía para el pan, "pan de libra"(460gr), "pan de libra y media" (690gr)

Comment: @walen I intended it to be about language, I agree that asking why this happens would be off-topic.

Comment: Y yo que pensaba que *furlong per fortnight* era una unidad habitual de velocidad ...

Answer (score 5):

The [*fanega*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanega) is still used in private contracts between rural land owners when buying or selling land.

I know this because I have copies of one such contract, from the 90s, for the renting of 3 *fanegas* of land; and I doubt that contract is "one of a kind".
Sadly, I can't get a picture of the contract right now (I might update later with one).

As an alternate source, I found this forum with [people discussing land renting prices in *pesetas* per *fanega* in 2011](https://www.agroterra.com/foro/foros/olivar-f6/arrendamiento-t16685.html). Same forum, another user looking to sell [an 18 *fanegas* olive-tree terrain](https://www.agroterra.com/foro/foros/olivar-f6/arrendamiento-de-olivar-t22390.html).

Comment: No soy marino por lo que no sé si se sigue usando el **nudo** (una **milla marina** por hora) para medir la velocidad de las embarcaciones. En el caso de la aeronáutica, seguro que sí.

Comment: Mis padres tienen algunas fincas pequeñas heredadas de mis abuelos, y muchas veces también usan el término "fanega" para refererirse a su superficie. No sólo por escrito, sino en conversaciones informales.

Answer (score 5):

En Argentina es completamente estándar usar *libras* para la presión de los neumáticos (propiamente, libra por pulgada cuadrada). Así que son dos medidas (libra y pulgada) que se usan en ese caso.

En aviación, es obligatorio para los aviones tener los altímetros en pies, y los velocímetros en millas por hora o en nudos. Curiosamente, la misma reglamentación **no** se aplica a los planeadores, y volábamos con altímetro en metros y velocímetro en km/h.

Answer (score 4):

In Colombia the corn and rice and most grains are still sold in *arrobas* (25 pounds = 11.5 kg) but the price is given by kg. (see http://www.corabastos.com.co/ lista de precios/granos)

Another unconventional unit of measure used frequently today is *bulto* or sack which is 50kg. This is used for potatos and all kinds of things that can be packed in a sack as well as cement.

As a coffee country we deal this beauty in *carga* and in *arroba* (https://www.federaciondecafeteros.org/static/files/precio_cafe.pdf) where *1 carga* is 125 kg. *Carga* comes from the number of *bultos* a mule is able to carry.

[image] http://www.lapatria.com/manizales/video-la-carga-lomo-de-mula-165566

A measure a little less used but still used on rural areas is [*pucha*](http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Pucha.php). They made a wooden box of 20x20x4 cms internal measurements, and you can buy rice, beans, etc. by *puchas* so instead of buying those products by weight you are buying them by volumen.
In the same way there are boxes for [*Cuartillo* and *media pucha*](http://www.elcolombiano.com/blogs/carlosmunera/montaneros-con-orgullo/1781).
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Chile, wholesale flour is still sold per **[quintal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintal)**, that is, in cotton or paper bags of approximately 46 kilograms. However, this measure no longer exists in the new sacks of plastic mesh, so now we also buy "*quintal de 40 kilos*" and "*quintal de 50 kilos*" (that is, in metric units).

In southern Chile, **[almud](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almud)** is still used, which is a rather arbitrary measure of the volume of potatoes and other farm products.

Answer (score 3):

En **fútbol americano** se usan las yardas para hablar de las distancias en el campo, independientemente del país en el que estés. El campo reglamentario está marcado en yardas y no tiene sentido hablar de otras medidas de longitud. Cierto que es un deporte originario de EEUU y mayoritaramente practicado allí, pero bueno, en otros países se sigue también y en ningún momento se usan los metros para referirse a las diferentes líneas del campo.

Curiosamente, en **rugby** se usan metros, a pesar de que son deportes relativamente similares. ¿Quizás porque el rugby es de origen europeo?

Quizás haya otros deportes en los que suceda esto (ahora no se me ocurre ninguno).

Answer (score 3):

In some zones of Colombia it's still used the word [plaza](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaza_(unidad_de_superficie)) as surface unit. Wikipedia says it's also called fanegada. A plaza is 6.400 m2.